# AWS Lambda repeatedly invoked by ALB every 35 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an ALB with a listener rule that forwards incoming requests (matched on path and host header) to a target group.  That target group targets a Lambda to process the request.

If I send a request to that ALB that matches that listener rule, something gets triggered that continually invokes the lambda every few seconds (about every 35 seconds).

If I replace the ALB as the trigger with API Gateway, the Lambda only gets invoked once.

I'm at a loss for why the ALB or the Target Group could somehow trigger the Lambda to be invoked more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a health check for your Lambda target group (TG), which you can [modify or disable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html#modify-health-check-settings) if you like. These are regular 'pings' to your Lambda to assert & test its status.

As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html#health-check-settings), 35 seconds is the default `HealthCheckIntervalSeconds` for a TG if the target type is a Lambda, which explains the timing:

> **HealthCheckIntervalSeconds**
>
> **The approximate amount of time, in seconds, between health checks of an individual target.** The range is 5–300 seconds. The default is 30 seconds if the target type is instance or ip and **35 seconds if the target type is lambda**.